# Django cache backend: how to implement callback when cache timeout

Tags: django, caching, callback, timeout

In order to get user online status. 
I cache the time of user's last request in  Django middleware using redis cache back-end:

```
cache.set('last_request_by _%s' % (user.username), 
            now, settings.USER_LAST_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
```

How to add callback when the cached value timed out, so I can write the timed out value into the database as user's last active time?